# "outer" keyword, Julia for-loop variable scope

Tags: for-loop, julia

I want to use a for-loop to implement an iterative method. At the end of the loop I also want to check if `max_iter` is reached:

```
function iterative_method()

    iter_max = 10

    for iter in 1:iter_max 
        # some computations
        # ...
        # if converged 
        #    break
        # end
    end

    @assert iter!=iter_max "max iteration = $iter_max reached!"

end
```

Unfortunately the `@assert` cannot work as `iter` is out of scope:

```
julia> iterative_method()
ERROR: UndefVarError: iter not defined
```

**Question:** how to make `iter` visible outside the for loop block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use `outer` as described in the [official doc: Loops-and-Comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Loops-and-Comprehensions)

```
function iterative_method()

    iter_max = 10

    local iter                           # <- declare "iter" variable
    for outer iter in 1:iter_max         # <- use "outer" keyword
        # some computations
        # ...
        # if converged 
        #    break
        # end
    end

    @assert iter!=iter_max "max iteration = $iter_max reached!"

end
```

which now works as expected:

```
julia> iterative_method()
ERROR: AssertionError: max iteration = 10 reached!
```

However, Julia core devs have expressed regret about adding this feature and will likely remove it in Julia 2.0, so it's probably clearer and simpler to express this with the following slightly more verbose version:

```
function iterative_method()

    iter_max = 10

    local iter
    for i in 1:iter_max
        iter = i
        # some computations
        # ...
        # if converged 
        #    break
        # end
    end

    @assert iter!=iter_max "max iteration = $iter_max reached!"

end
```

Comment: thanks for posting that - I have not seen `outer` discussed on SO yet

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel yes, I was surprised to find it "hidden" in the documentation, that's why I posted it. Thank you for your comment.